# Laravel: search through relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5

I don't know if it is actually posible but it might look like this:

Schema:

```
User
id, name, last_name, etc.

Condition
id, name

User_Condition
id, user_id, condition_id, active, start_date, end_date
```

I want to be able to do something similar to this: `$user->conditions->active()` or `$user->conditions->active` where it returns any row/relations in which active = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get all the **active conditions** of a **user**, right?

If so, you get them by following query.

```
echo $user->conditions()->where('user_condition.active', true)->get();
```

Make sure you make a `belongsToMany` relationship in `user model`

```
public function conditions()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Condition', 'user_condition');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `with` filter, also known as *Eager Load Constraints*.

```
$user->with['UserCondition'=>function($query){
                                 return $query->whereActive(1);
                             }
            ];
```

(Assuming `UserCondition` relationship has been set in the `User` eloquent model).

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent